# Prevent component from being added in the Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I am looking of a way to disable the possibility of attaching my MonoBehaviour component in the Unity Editor.
So I don't want my component to appear anywhere visible by the user.

The reason is that I attach this component manually from a script with `AddComponent<T>()`. So this is more a convenience question, I just don't want the user to think he has to add my component manually in order for my plugin to work. (if he does anyway, that doesn't cause any trouble. Again, this is just convenience)

#### Precisions

I am writing a library (dll plugin), so I cannot use the trick of naming the file differently from my component, but that is exactly the effect I'm looking for.

I also tried to simply put my class as internal because that's really what it is, the assembly should be the only one to have access to this component. However, I'm afraid inheriting from MonoBehaviour even with an internal class makes the component available in the editor...

The `HideInInspector` attribute doesn't seem to work on a class.

I am calling `AddComponent` from a static method with [`RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.AfterSceneLoad)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute-ctor.html) so I won't have any other behaviour to rely on.

Quite a challenge, if we find an answer, that would be luxury.
Any idea? Thank you very much

Comment: Is it a runtime AddComponent or an EditorScript? Doing it in runtime may be a performance issue for the user - If it doesn't cause any issues maybe leave it up to the user to decide if the user want to add it manually?

Comment: Yes it is at runtime but once, when the first scene loads. To be fair, I'm writing a library for a service so if he downloads my library, it is already because he wants my behaviours to be there...

Comment: I see! Unfortunately I don't have the answer to your question. You can't use `[RequireComponent( typeof(YourScript) )]` instead of AddComponent?

Comment: Not really. My component is instantiated from a [`RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute-ctor.html) so I don't have any other MonoBehaviour to hold on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple solution is to make your class an inner class of some owner:

```
class NotAMonoBehaviour {
  class MyMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    //etc.
  }
}
```

You can add the class easily enough:

```
gameObject.AddComponent<NotAMonoBehaviour.MyMonoBehaviour>()
```

And it will not show up in the inspector's Add Component list. Setting using the hide flags as suggested will also stop it from showing up in the inspector itself, although that can't be relied upon entirely, as you can open the Debug view in the inspector and still see hidden components.

Comment: I cannot believe that actually worked! Man this is brilliant, huge thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> So I don't want my component to appear anywhere visible by the user.

The snippet below should hide your script from the Editor (Inspector and Hierarchy).

```
this.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
this.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInInspector;
```

> I am looking of a way to disable the possibility of attaching my
>   MonoBehaviour component in the Unity Editor

As long as your script inherits from `MonoBehaviour`, you **can't** prevent people attaching it to a GameObject.

Although, you can make it so that when they attach it their GameObject, you throw an error and then destroy that component. Have a variable you set to true. You can can a function from your plugin to set this variable to true from your plugin so that your script will not destroy.

Example code:

```
public class MoveTowards : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool callFromMyPlugin = false;

    //Call from your plugin to not destroy this script
    public void keepAlive()
    {
        callFromMyPlugin = true;
    }

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        //Hides component from users
        hideFromUser();


        if (!callFromMyPlugin)
        {
            destroyThisComponent();
        }
        yield return null;

    }

    //Hides component in the Hierarchy and Inspector
    void hideFromUser()
    {
        this.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
        this.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInInspector;

    }

    //Destroys this component
    void destroyThisComponent()
    {
        Debug.LogError("You are not allowed to add this component to a GameObject");
        DestroyImmediate(this);
        Debug.LogWarning("This component is now destroyed");
    }
}
```

When people call it like this:

```
GameObject testObj = new GameObject("Test");
MoveTowards script = testObj.AddComponent<MoveTowards>();
```

They will get the error below and the script will destroy itself:

[image]

Now, if you call create it from your plugin and call the `keepAlive` function, the script should stay:

```
GameObject testObj = new GameObject("Test");
MoveTowards script = testObj.AddComponent<MoveTowards>();
script.keepAlive();
```

**Note:**

This is **not** an Editor script and it made to work when you click the "Play" button but you can use `[ExecuteInEditMode]` to make it execute in the Editor.

Comment: This is really well thought out, thank you very much! It does what I was trying to achieve: tell the user they don't have to add it themselves. I'll mark it as the solution by the end of today if it is the best solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I use Monobehaviour.Reset() method to prevent addcomponent in Editor.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html

> Reset is called when the user hits the Reset button in the Inspector's
>   context menu or when adding the component the first time. This
>   function is only called in editor mode. Reset is most commonly used to
>   give good default values in the inspector.

```
    private void Reset()
    {
        if (this.GetType() == typeof(MyCustomClass))
        {
            DestroyImmediate( this );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not bat at all! Will give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: Great idea to use `MonoBehaviour.Reset()`. My previous solution involved `MonoBehaviour.Awake()` and `ExecuteInEditMode `.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding it with AddComponent, maybe you want to remove the MonoBehaviour part of your component.

Consider you have that main component that creates the sub component in Start:

```
public class TopComp: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start(){
        this.gameObject.AddComponent<SubComponent>();
    }
}
```

turn that into:

```
public class TopComp: MonoBehaviour
{
    private SubComponent sub = null;
    void Start(){
        this.sub = new SubComponent();
    }
}
public class SubComponent{ }
```

The problem is that you most likely wanted to use all the Unity callbacks. Add them to the TopComponent and call the SubComponent explicitly.

```
public class TopComp: MonoBehaviour
{
    private SubComponent sub = null;
    void Start(){
        this.sub = new SubComponent();
    }
    void OnEnable(){ this.sub.OnEnable();} 
    void Update(){ this.Update();}
}
public class SubComponent{
    public void OnEnable(){}
    public void Update(){}
}
```

Comment: Hum, almost what I need. I am instantiating my component in a function with this attribute: [`RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.AfterSceneLoad)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute-ctor.html)
So I don't have another GameObject to use as the holder...

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution, but I'm not 100% sure. It is naming your Component differently from cs file name.

Comment: Unity requires the component name to be the same as the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the class abstract, and it can't be added.

Comment: Here is a comment (by  
yo.ian.g) from an already deleted answer which also proposed the same: The asker is asking for a technique that will hide the MonoBehavior from Unity Editor but will still be instantiable in their script. Are you sure that an abstract class can be instantiated?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33929620)

Answer (score 0):

Use AddComponentMenu attribute with an empty string:

```
[AddComponentMenu("")]
class MyHiddenComponent : MonoBehaviour
{}
```